# When I'm in, I'm all in [meaning]

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

From [**describing personality**](http://richardstep.com/personality-types/how-would-you-describe-your-personality-to-a-stranger/):

> Bubbly, outgoing with a great sense of humor. I’m willing to help
>   anyone in need and when I’m in, I’m all in

when I'm in, I'm all in. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m all in

is also used in a poker context. See [all in](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/all+in):

> 2) Games staking all of one's chips, as in poker.

meaning the same as:

> 3)  Putting all of one's available resources into an effort.

Answer (score 1):

`To be in` is like `to be ready to`.
`To be all in` is like `To be totally committed to something`.

Therefore it means that when you're determined (~= ready), you'll be committed to do it.